# Distortion when exporting from QGIS to DXF?

Tags: qgis, export, autocad, dxf

I'm rather new in the GIS world, and I'm having a weird problem that I have no idea how to solve.

I received a GIS map and I wanted to export one of the layers as DXF; I selected the correspondent CRS (WGS 84 / UTM zone 47N for Myanmar) and I generated a DXF, but when I opened the file it was somehow distorted.. I mean that the Y dimension was right, but the X dimension had "shrinked". In the attached image you can see that the new polygon (blue) matches the original boundary (orange) on the top (it also matches on the bottom), but not on the left and right sides.

Any idea of what can be the reason of this?

I'm using AutoCAD 2016 to open the DXF file.

[image: Image of the horizontal axis deformation between the original drawing and the generated DXF]

Answer (score 1):

AutoCAD wants the data to be in feet or meters not degrees.  Try and export the features in EPSG 3857 and see what that looks like.

Comment: Thank you! I did so but also did not work.. Finally I think I won't work in Autocad, just QGIS, so that I don't have these troubles.. But I still would like to know what went wrong!

Comment: Can you upload a copy of your data?

Comment: Sorry, at the end I found that the problem was on the image I used as a reference, apparently they used another CRS and that's why it looked different, but the areas in my DXF were right. Thank you anyway!